# Disabled button with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is loaded on clicking prev button. I want to disable this button when there is no more articles. Preferably  i would like button to disappear.

```
function getPrev(item, article) {
  for (var i = 0, len = article.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (article[i].id === item) {
    return (i - 1 >= 0) ? article[i - 1] : null;
  }     
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you want to hide your button, use

```
$("#buttonid").hide();
```

If you want to disable it,

```
$("#buttonid").prop("disabled",true);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is -

```
document.getElemenyById('buttonid').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Just remember to set the style to 'block' when there are articles